# how to declare global variables in requirejs for angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I want to declare some variables globally like

```
var serviceApp = angular.module('myApp.services', []);
var directiveApp = angular.module('myApp.directives', [])
```

so that I can use this variables in multiple files.
I want to include more than two service files in my app. If I write these vars in each file, it overwrites another file.
Is there any solution to get out of it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can declare them as global variables and access them anywhere:

```
var globalConfig = {
    serviceApp: '....',
    dircetiveApp: '...'
};
```

This is still accessible in any of your modules:

```
define(function(){
    var serviceApp = window.globalConfig.serviceApp;
});
```

I suggest you put them into object as shown above, to avoid polluting global namespace.